# object-fit:cover Not Working with ImageCapture.takePhoto on Mobile

Tags: android, css, webrtc, image-capture

I try to show the photo with `object-fit:cover` taken by the [ImageCapture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageCapture). It works perfectly with Chrome on desktop. However, the `object-fit:cover` style is NOT working with Chrome on Android for ALL devices and emulators.

A minimal sample for this issue can be found [here](https://seanwu1105.github.io/try-image-capture/).

The size of `<img id="photoImg" />` is fixed to 200 * 400 px to demonstrate the `object-fit:cover` style. The `src` of the image is generated from the `ImageCapture.takePhoto()` method and converted the blob to URL via `URL.createObjectURL()` function.

The following the result from Chrome on desktop, which is working perfectly.

[image]

Sadly, the following result from Chrome on Android (Sony Xperia 1) has the distorted image ratio. It seems the `object-fit:cover` does not work.

[image]

I have used [Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) to confirm that other `object-fit` values, such as `object-fit:contain` do work as expected.

I suspect that the `Blob` from `ImageCapture` might miss some critical pieces of information for the image ratio to be correctly calculated but I do not know how to investigate further.

How can I make the `object-fit:cover` work on mobile devices with Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, I find the root cause: [a Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1082669). It has been fixed and released in version 89. Thus, this question is no longer valid.